# How do I run filtering rules in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

Is there a way to run rules that you set up after emails have been received?

I can't see anything in the settings. It is quite hard to search for as the web app as the same name as the desktop application.

Answer (score -1):

When I view Outlook.com, there is a sort of gear symbol at the top right.  Clicking on this drops down a menu which includes "manage rules"  They apparently moved this from a previous location.

Answer (score -2):

Click on the settings icon and click **More mail settings**. Under the "Customizing Outlook" heading, click **Rules for sorting new messages**.

Comment: That allows me to create rules (which I have done). I would like to run them. Is there a button hidden there that I am not seeing?

Comment: From the rules page:

_You can set up rules to **automatically** handle messages as they come in. You can flag messages, move them to folders, set alerts for your mobile phone, and more._

I set up rules on my own account and they were effective immediately just from setting them up using that page.

Comment: The key part being `as they come in`. I would like to run the rules `after they have come in`.  Did making those rules automatically move everything to that particular folder? I appreciate your help by the way, thanks.